# zsh write to a file whose path is stored in a variable

Tags: zsh

I am trying to append text to a file, where the file name is stored in a variable:

```
x="/path/to/file.txt"
echo "some text here" >> "${=x}"
```

But it does not work -- as far as I can tell, nothing happens, and the line does not get written to the file. As I am testing it right now, I am echoing text directly to the file (without going through a variable) in other lines of the script. All of that is working -- my file is just missing the single line that I am testing the variable with. For clarity, I am including the actual code below.

$x expands properly if I echo it, and replacing "${=x}" with the file name manually works. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Details:
zsh 5.8
MacOS Big Sur

Actual code (with company name obfuscated):

```
# Define log file location.
# Log file can be updated later for portability. But for now, I want to keep it in a personal directory.
#
readonly LOG_FILE="/Users/jim.turner.m1/OneDrive\ -\ obfuscated/Shell\ Scripts/sanitize.log"

# Prep log file
#
prep_log()
{
#       echo "==============================================================" >> "${=LOG_FILE}"
        echo "Sanitize.sh started $(date)." >> ~/OneDrive\ -\ obfuscated/Shell\ Scripts/sanitize.log
        echo "Sanitizing $(pwd)." >> ~/OneDrive\ -\ obfuscated/Shell\ Scripts/sanitize.log
        echo "==============================================================" >> ~/OneDrive\ -\ obfuscated/Shell\ Scripts/sanitize.log
        echo >> ~/OneDrive\ -\ obfuscated/Shell\ Scripts/sanitize.log
}
```

Which results in:

```
Sanitize.sh started Fri May 21 09:21:27 EDT 2021. 
Sanitizing /Users/jim.turner.m1/Desktop/untitled folder.
==============================================================
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what "it does not work" means. Do you get an error? Is the file not created? Is the file created but left empty? Is no data appended? Is data overwritten? Is wrong data appended? Also, does it work if you use `echo "some text here" >> "$x"`?

Comment: Done. Using "$x" does not work. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Choose your quoting operator. Either use backslash, `"..."` or `'...'` but not all at the same time. Also `${=var}` is to split a var, it doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the variable to a string that includes escaped spaces. You are doing `var='foo\ bar'` which means that the string is saved *with* the `\`. However, you are then using the variable quoted (good) but that means it is looking for a file called `foo\ bar` and not a file called `foo bar`. When setting the variable, *either* quote the string *or* escape the spaces, but don't do both:

```
readonly log_file=/Users/jim.turner.m1/OneDrive\ -\ obfuscated/Shell\ Scripts/sanitize.log
```

or

```
readonly log_file="/Users/jim.turner.m1/OneDrive - obfuscated/Shell Scripts/sanitize.log"
```

Either of those should work. Also note how I changed your variable to use lower case letters since it is bad practice to use CAPS for shell variables as that is the convention for environment variables and can sometimes lead to variable name collisions. Finally, very minor point, you don't need `$(pwd)`, you can just use the `PWD` variable and you might want to use a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to keep things tidy and clean. Putting all this together with a couple more improvements gives:

```
# Define log file location.
# Log file can be updated later for portability. But for now, I want to keep it in a personal directory.
#
readonly log_file="/Users/jim.turner.m1/OneDrive - obfuscated/Shell Scripts/sanitize.log"

# Prep log file
#
prep_log()
{
  cat << EoF > "$log_file"
==============================================================
Sanitize.sh started $(date).
Sanitizing $PWD
==============================================================

EoF

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working perfectly now.